# Is there a way to set attribute with URL as a value to ABBR tag?

Tags: html, abbr

Is there a standards-compliant way to set attribute with URL as a value to ABBR tag?

```
<abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets">CSS</abbr>
```

I need something similar, but valid... It should NOT be clickable, of coz.
Any suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:
[HTML5 Custom Data Attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)